# Android DatagramSocket receive buffer size

Tags: android, sockets, udp, packet-loss

I am trying to set/increase the receive buffer size of a datagram socket. I would like to do this since I am experiencing some random packet loss when sending data between a PC and the Android device which lie on the same local network and I would like to test if increasing the buffer size would have any effect in reducing this UDP packet loss. I am trying to set the buffer size using the below code.

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
socket.setReceiveBufferSize(655360);
```

and then later on (before I start reading from the socket) I check the receive buffer size as follows:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Size: " + socket.getReceiveBufferSize());
```

However, the log message always displays a buffer size of 163840. 
What is the problem with this code? Should I set the receive buffer size in another way.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The log message always displays a buffer size of 163840.

That's what the platform gave you.

> What is the problem with this code?

Nothing. You need to read the Javadoc. The platform may adjust the value you supply up or down. "Because `SO_RCVBUF` is a hint, applications that want to verify what size the buffers were set to should call `getReceiveBufferSize().`"

You don't need a socket receive buffer of 640k. Packet loss happens mostly in the network, and only at the target if you are slow reading.

Comment: So the buffer size specified is just an indication? 
I thought it was a minimum value since the doc says:
"This is a hint to the kernel; the kernel may use a larger buffer."

I know that UDP is connectionless and therefore packet loss will happen but I think that I am having too much packet loss. Maybe the problem is with my reading thread.

Comment: The kernel may also use a smaller buffer, no matter what the Javadoc may say. It isn't up to Java, it's up to the kernel. I suspect the problem is in the network rather than the code. 'Too much' is subjective. How much?

Comment: Well it is not always constant but on average I would say that for every 20 packets I lose one. But it is not always constant. I need to modify my code to cater for packet loss since as you said it is bound to happen. Thanks

Comment: That shows it isn't the socket receive buffer. You can only practically depend on 534 bytes of payload, times 20 ~= 10k. So 64k would be much more than adequate, and 640k entirely unnecessary.